# access Google Music from other apps

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I've been fiddling around with Tasker recently and I think it would be cool to be able to pass Google music a string input from the user that Google Music would use to generate a radio station that could be played. I know there's no official api at this point, and I'm even surer I wouldn't know what to do with it were that not the case.

I Can access a bunch of gmusic activities thru the "Secure Settings" Tasker plugin--there's a particularly interesting activity called 'CreateMixActivity,' but I can't find any info on it--and have between playing around with Intents, but don't really know how or where I should start experimenting.

Any input/questions would be greatly appreciated (first post btw)

Chucksef

Answer (score 0):

This is as close as you are gonna get o an API, this is using **Python** but you are welcome to go through the code and write your a fork using **Java/Android**.

https://github.com/simon-weber/Unofficial-Google-Music-API